# Ubuntu 14.04 Unity not functioning, no launcher

Tags: 14.04, launcher, taskbar

Yesterday I turned my computer to find that the launcher was missing.   In addition, I could not using ctrl-alt-t would bring up a blank white screen.   The only terminal could be found by clicking ctrl-alt-f1.   I used ccsm to turn on Unity.   Unity panel service was working.   I installed tweak tool.   I did all the troubleshooting I could find related to this subject.   Nothing would work.   I ultimately reinstalled Ubuntu 13.10.   Also, I do not have an nvidia graphics card.   I have an intel integrated graphics controller.

Some of the troubleshooting I tried were found:

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951)

[ubuntu 14.04 unity desktop without panel and launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452671/ubuntu-14-04-unity-desktop-without-panel-and-launcher)

[how to fix: no unity, no launcher no dash in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451159/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-14-04)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008891

Comment: This does not seem like a question!  I just had the same issue on another laptop I use.